# Incomplete transfers to amazon s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

What happens to incomplete transfers while uploading to amazon s3. I am using boto(python) for 
uploading.For example,i have 5 gb free in amazon s3 cloud and  I want to upload 3 gb of data,
but after uploading 1 gb of data, i loose the internet connection. what happens in s3? . 
Is 1 gb charged for my account i.e is 1gb considered as used or incomplete transfers 
discarded?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incoming traffic to `S3` is not charged. If a connection was lost, the file is not transferred, it is lost. So, nothing is stored on `S3` and hence you will not be charged for it. Refer: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/